# How to centralize the error handling for API calls in react (with Axios)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am using Axios for back end calls in my react application. For manageability I wrote a common function, used it for making back end calls. I need suggestion on how to centralize the error handling and best way to show it on UI.

```
    import Axios from "axios";


    // Backend api calls to :: 
    export default function apiService(requestParams) {
        const accessToken = sessionStorage.getItem("access_token");
        requestParams.headers = {
            'authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        };

        return Axios(requestParams);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use axios interceptors:

```
// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

https://github.com/axios/axios

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you can use *interceptors*, or just configure your default client:

```
/**
 * Create an Axios Client with defaults
 */
const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: API.BASEURL,
  headers: {
    Authorization: getAuth(),
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': 1728000,
  },
});

/**
 * Request Wrapper with default success/error actions
 */
const request = (options) => {
  const onSuccess = (response) => options.raw ? response : response.data;
    // console.debug('Request Successful!', response);
    // If options.raw is true, return all response

  const onError = (error) => {
    // console.error('Request Failed:', error.config);

    if (error.response) {
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        // console.error('Unauthorized');
      } else {
        // Request was made but server responded with something
        // other than 2xx
        // console.error('Status:', error.response.status);
        // console.error('Data:', error.response.data);
        // console.error('Headers:', error.response.headers);
      }
    } else {
      // Something else happened while setting up the request
      // triggered the error
      // console.error('Error Message:', error.message);
    }

    return Promise.reject(error.response || error.message);
  };

  return client(options)
    .then(onSuccess)
    .catch(onError);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a dedicated java script method to make the API call and handle the error. Refer the below method.

```
const makeAPICall = async (url, method, payload = null, params = null) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method, url, payload, params
    });

    if (isEmpty(response.success) || response.success) {
      if(response.data.warnings) {
        warningHandler(response.data.warnings)
      }
      if(response.data.serviceErrors) {
        serviceErrorHandler(response.data.serviceErrors)
      }
      return response.data;
    }
    errorHanlder(response.data.error.message);

    return response.data;

  } catch (e) {
    return errorHandler(e);
  }
};
```

The Api will return  serviceerror if there is a problem in the backend in that case we need to check whether there are any serviceerror object is available or not. Tf there is any service error then **serviceErrorHandler** will handle the error.
In some cases API will fail with 500, 501, 404 etc error then in that case **errorHandler** function will handle those error.